# SQLAlchemy return model from outerjoin

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

Given a model :

```
class Model(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'dummy'

    insert_date = Column(Date())
    pk = Column(Integer())
    ...
```

I need to replicated the following sql query:

```
select a.* 
from (select * from dummy where insert_date = TODAY) a
left join (select distinct pk from dummy where insert_date < TODAY) b 
using (pk)
where b.(whatever) IS/IS NOT Null
```

but I need sqlalchemy to return objects, not a tuple of columns (which is what I'm currently working with).

In words, I'm basically achieving,

> "get all dummy records that were inserted for the first time
>   yesterday"

and

> "get all dummy records that were updated yesterday"

depending on the IS or IS NOT NULL part of the statement. Each
pk will have multiple entries. You cannot rely on filtering by an update date. **It should be noted that pk will be a primary key in the next table, but it isn't a primary key in the current table.**

For example,

in dummy:

```
Inserted Tuesday, pk=1, ....
Inserted Wednesday, pk=1, ....
Inserted Wednesday, pk=2, ....
```

pk=1 would be returned with 'IS NOT NULL'
pk=2 would be returned with 'IS NULL'

I’ve gotten the following to return records:

```
a = session.query(model).filter(model.date_retrieval==task_date).subquery()
b = session.query(model).filter(model.date_retrieval<task_date).subquery()
c = session.query(a, b).outerjoin(b, and_(a.c.pk==b.c.pk, a.c.seq==b.c.seq))
```

this returns:

```
c.all()[0] : 
(datetime.date(2015, 7, 1),
0,
1511,
u'431889',
u'7',
u'N',
u'0',
u'0',
u'0',
u'',
u'',
u'',
u'2',
u'5',
u'554428',
u'H',
u'9',
u'901',
datetime.date(2015, 6, 30),
0,
3487,
u'431889',
u'7',
u'N',
u'0',
u'0',
u'0',
u'',
u'',
u'',
u'2',
u'5',
u'554428',
u'H',
u'9',
u'901')
```

and then something along the lines of

```
[indv for indv in c if indv[-1] ] and  [indv for indv in c if indv[-1] == None ]
```

to divide IS NOT NULL from IS NULL cases

**EDIT 1:**

The primary key is a composite key consisting of insert_date, insert_seq 
('2015-07-08', 0), ('2015-07-08', 1), ('2015-07-08', 2)...

Comment: Not sure what your question is. From the title (not really from the description) I guess you want to get the 'Model' object for each of the `pk`  that result from your `join` statement, since you want to update it or something like that. I would just access `Model` by `pk` for the rows you need to update. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do what you want with the code below:

```
a = aliased(Model, name="a")
b = aliased(Model, name="b")
q = (
    session
    .query(a)
    .outerjoin(b, and_(a.pk == b.pk, b.insert_date < task_date))
    .filter(a.insert_date == task_date)
    .filter(b.pk == None)
    # or: .filter(b.pk != None)
)
```

It does not produce the same `sql`, but i think it is semantically the same.

The other (and in my opinion, cleaner) way to do it would be using `exists` or `~exists`:

```
q = (
    session
    .query(a)
    .filter(a.insert_date == task_date)
    .filter(
        exists(
        # or: ~exists(
            select([b.pk])
            .where(a.pk == b.pk)
            .where(b.insert_date < task_date)
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: I thought the latter would generally be slower. In any case, the desired result is achieved. I hadn't been able to query a and outerjoin b because I wasn't using the correct "aliasing" method. I was using subquery and had also looked into model.__table__.alias(name='a'), neither of which worked. Anyway, thanks a lot.